# How to Backup Postgres Database on AWS and restore locally?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-backups, database-restore

I'm working on trying to setup my local database with some mock data to work with. We have a development AWS account with a postgres database. I would like to create a backup of it, export it to my local computer, and restore to my local postgres database.

I've been trying to find how to do this online, but everything I'm finding is on how to backup to AWS and to restore back to AWS. I tried creating a snapshot and exporting it via S3 - but the snapshot doesn't produce a sql file to restore from like I was expecting.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the only chance you have is `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`.

Even if Amazon lets you get your hands on its file system backups, which I doubt, they may be of little use to you, since Amazon runs modified versions of PostgreSQL and you cannot be sure that the physical file format is identical to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I see. So I guess I need to figure out how to remote into the AWS dev database instance next. Thanks!